# Can I game the Legendary badge with self-awarded bounties?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, daily-reputation-badges, gaming-the-system

I just set a bounty on one of my questions, where I have the only answer so far. If nobody else answers, or if nobody else gives a deserving answer, I will award myself the bounty and get +150 rep that day. Correct?

So:

Does that count toward Mortarboard/Epic/Legendary?

Theoretically, I could set 200-rep bounties on odd-numbered days, then come back and award myself the bounties on even-numbered days. Sure I'd lose rep on odd-numbered days, but gain huge rep on even-numbered days.

Does that even work?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work and again think of is a price you pay for advertising

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot award yourself a bounty, not even automatically (which would be a loss regardless).

Comment: Ah. I missed that part. Thanks. But what will happen to the bounty I set on my own question, if nobody else answers?

Comment: The reputation would disappear and be awarded to nobody.

Comment: Bounties do count towards these badges. It's 200 reputation from *anything* positive, and downvotes aren't counted anymore either.

Comment: Speaking of which, this post just earned me the Mortarboard badge on Meta.

Comment: @minitech its better this way, less whining about the order of actions. I hit the rep cap the other day, but before the day ended, I saw an answer that needed a down vote towards the end if the day. Voila, no more rep cap. But if I found that post an hour before, I would have had an up vote that would have partially count